# combine 2 or more json data in golang

Tags: go

I have following two json data :

First json data :

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "carrierCode": "TK",
        "outboundAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "legtraveltime": "PT14H15M",
        "totalJourneyTime": 0,
        "recordSet": "GDS@PUBLISHED@E@1|UN3FEST|FB00|TK|1||ADT=ADT,CHD=CHD|1,2|LHR|DAC|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||322.000000|771.120000;1|TLXN2XPC|FB05|TK|1|||3,4|DAC|LHR|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||0.000000|0.000000ÞÞGBP1093.12",
        "lastTicketingDate": "2022-01-11T23:59:59",
        "legFareClass": "Economy",
        "supportedfunctions": "None",
        "requirementValues": 0,
        "numStops": 0,
        "departureDate": "",
        "origin": "",
        "arrivalDate": "",
        "destination": "",
        "airsegments": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "carrierCode": "TK",
        "outboundAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "legtraveltime": "PT16H25M",
        "totalJourneyTime": 0,
        "recordSet": "GDS@PUBLISHED@E@1|UN3FEST|FB00|TK|1||ADT=ADT,CHD=CHD|1,2|LHR|DAC|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||322.000000|771.120000;1|TLXN2XPC|FB05|TK|1|||3,4|DAC|LHR|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||0.000000|0.000000ÞÞGBP1093.12",
        "lastTicketingDate": "2022-01-11T23:59:59",
        "legFareClass": "Economy",
        "supportedfunctions": "None",
        "requirementValues": 0,
        "numStops": 0,
        "departureDate": "",
        "origin": "",
        "arrivalDate": "",
        "destination": "",
        "airsegments": null
    }
]
```

Second json data :

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-09T00:30:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-09",
        "ArrivalTime": "00:30:00",
        "bookingclass": "U",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "LHR",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-08T17:40:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-08",
        "DepartureTime": "17:40:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "UN3FEST/FB00",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "1972",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "DAC",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-09T13:55:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-09",
        "ArrivalTime": "13:55:00",
        "bookingclass": "U",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "IST",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-09T03:35:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-09",
        "DepartureTime": "03:35:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "UN3FEST/FB00",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "712",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-22T05:40:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-22",
        "ArrivalTime": "05:40:00",
        "bookingclass": "T",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "DAC",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-21T23:30:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-21",
        "DepartureTime": "23:30:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "TLXN2XPC/FB05",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "723",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "LHR",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-22T09:55:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-22",
        "ArrivalTime": "09:55:00",
        "bookingclass": "T",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "IST",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-22T08:50:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-22",
        "DepartureTime": "08:50:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "TLXN2XPC/FB05",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "1979",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "TK-1972-LHR-IST-202202081740-MG:O@C:TK@|TK-712-IST-DAC-202202090335-MG:I@C:TK@||LEG=1",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-09T00:30:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-09",
        "ArrivalTime": "00:30:00",
        "bookingclass": "U",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "LHR",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-08T17:40:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-08",
        "DepartureTime": "17:40:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "UN3FEST",
        "faretype": "Published",
        "FlightNumber": "1972",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Standard",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    }
]
```

I want to append or merge 2 json data .
I wrote following code
:

```golang
airsegmentss := []models.Airsegments{}
for _, flt := range flights {
    for _, arg := range airsegments {
        if arg.Availstring == flt.Availstring {
            airsegmentss = append(airsegmentss, arg)
            flightss := models.Flights{
                Airsegments: airsegmentss,
            }
            fmt.Println(flightss)
            flightssJson, err := json.Marshal(flightss)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(string(flightssJson))
        }
    }
}
```

It gives following error which is not valid:

```json
{0      0     0 0     [{1 PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X  IST 2022-02-09T00:30:00 2022-02-09 00:30:00 U Y Economy TK https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png LHR 2022-02-08T17:40:00 2022-02-08 17:40:00 333  UN3FEST/FB00 Negotiated 1972  9  Cat35 0}]}
{"id":0,"availstring":"","carrierCode":"","outboundAirlineCode":"","image":"","legtraveltime":"","totalJourneyTime":0,"recordSet":"","lastTicketingDate":"","legFareClass":"","supportedfunctions":"","requirementValues":0,"numStops":0,"departureDate":"","origin":"","arrivalDate":"","destination":"","airsegments":[{"id":1,"availstring":"PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X","flightType":"","ArrivalAirportCode":"IST","arrivaldatetime":"2022-02-09T00:30:00","ArrivalDate":"2022-02-09","ArrivalTime":"00:30:00","bookingclass":"U","cabinclass":"Y","CabinClass":"Economy","OperatingAirlineCode":"TK","image":"https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png","DepartureAirportCode":"LHR","departuredatetime":"2022-02-08T17:40:00","DepartureDate":"2022-02-08","DepartureTime":"17:40:00","equipmentcode":"333","equipmentname":"","farebase":"UN3FEST/FB00","faretype":"Negotiated","FlightNumber":"1972","freebaggageallowance":"","freeseats":9,"mealcode":"","subfaretype":"Cat35","journeyDuration":0}]}
{0      0     0 0     [{1 PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X  IST 2022-02-09T00:30:00 2022-02-09 00:30:00 U Y Economy TK https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png LHR 2022-02-08T17:40:00 2022-02-08 17:40:00 333  UN3FEST/FB00 Negotiated 1972  9  Cat35 0} {1 PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X  DAC 2022-02-09T13:55:00 2022-02-09 13:55:00 U Y Economy TK https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png IST 2022-02-09T03:35:00 2022-02-09 03:35:00 333  UN3FEST/FB00 Negotiated 712  9  Cat35 0}]}
{"id":0,"availstring":"","carrierCode":"","outboundAirlineCode":"","image":"","legtraveltime":"","totalJourneyTime":0,"recordSet":"","lastTicketingDate":"","legFareClass":"","supportedfunctions":"","requirementValues":0,"numStops":0,"departureDate":"","origin":"","arrivalDate":"","destination":"","airsegments":[{"id":1,"availstring":"PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X","flightType":"","ArrivalAirportCode":"IST","arrivaldatetime":"2022-02-09T00:30:00","ArrivalDate":"2022-02-09","ArrivalTime":"00:30:00","bookingclass":"U","cabinclass":"Y","CabinClass":"Economy","OperatingAirlineCode":"TK","image":"https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png","DepartureAirportCode":"LHR","departuredatetime":"2022-02-08T17:40:00","DepartureDate":"2022-02-08","DepartureTime":"17:40:00","equipmentcode":"333","equipmentname":"","farebase":"UN3FEST/FB00","faretype":"Negotiated","FlightNumber":"1972","freebaggageallowance":"","freeseats":9,"mealcode":"","subfaretype":"Cat35","journeyDuration":0},{"id":1,"availstring":"PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X","flightType":"","ArrivalAirportCode":"DAC","arrivaldatetime":"2022-02-09T13:55:00","ArrivalDate":"2022-02-09","ArrivalTime":"13:55:00","bookingclass":"U","cabinclass":"Y","CabinClass":"Economy","OperatingAirlineCode":"TK","image":"https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png","DepartureAirportCode":"IST","departuredatetime":"2022-02-09T03:35:00","DepartureDate":"2022-02-09","DepartureTime":"03:35:00","equipmentcode":"333","equipmentname":"","farebase":"UN3FEST/FB00","faretype":"Negotiated","FlightNumber":"712","freebaggageallowance":"","freeseats":9,"mealcode":"","subfaretype":"Cat35","journeyDuration":0}]}
{0      0     0 0     [{1 PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X  IST 2022-02-09T00:30:00 2022-02-09 00:30:00 U Y Economy TK https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png LHR 2022-02-08T17:40:00 2022-02-08 17:40:00 333  UN3FEST/FB00 Negotiated 1972  9  Cat35 0}]}
{"id":0,"availstring":"","carrierCode":"","outboundAirlineCode":"","image":"","legtraveltime":"","totalJourneyTime":0,"recordSet":"","lastTicketingDate":"","legFareClass":"","supportedfunctions":"","requirementValues":0,"numStops":0,"departureDate":"","origin":"","arrivalDate":"","destination":"","airsegments":[{"id":1,"availstring":"PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X","flightType":"","ArrivalAirportCode":"IST","arrivaldatetime":"2022-02-09T00:30:00","ArrivalDate":"2022-02-09","ArrivalTime":"00:30:00","bookingclass":"U","cabinclass":"Y","CabinClass":"Economy","OperatingAirlineCode":"TK","image":"https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png","DepartureAirportCode":"LHR","departuredatetime":"2022-02-08T17:40:00","DepartureDate":"2022-02-08","DepartureTime":"17:40:00","equipmentcode":"333","equipmentname":"","farebase":"UN3FEST/FB00","faretype":"Negotiated","FlightNumber":"1972","freebaggageallowance":"","freeseats":9,"mealcode":"","subfaretype":"Cat35","journeyDuration":0}]}

]}
```

How do I append 2 or more json data . It should check if conditions and if two id of 2 or more json data matches then one json data should append with another one.

Note:
In php code:

```php
$air  = array();
$flights = $flights->map(function($item) use ($airsegments){
              foreach($airsegments as $airsegment)
              {
                if(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '',($airsegment['availstring'].''.$airsegment['id']))
                  == preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '',($item['availstring'].''.$item['id'])))
                {
                  $air[]   = $airsegment;
                  }
                 }
                return collect($item)->put('airsegments', $air);
              });
```

The above code works perfectly in php. Since I am rewriting the whole php code in golang.

Comment: It's hard to understand how you're trying to merge the data. Could you explain what data is in the 2 JSON files and what the relationship is?

Answer (score 0):

I made a example(most of it to setup with the same data), didn't have your models, so please substitute the proper types. This should do what you want.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    j1 := `
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "carrierCode": "TK",
        "outboundAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "legtraveltime": "PT14H15M",
        "totalJourneyTime": 0,
        "recordSet": "GDS@PUBLISHED@E@1|UN3FEST|FB00|TK|1||ADT=ADT,CHD=CHD|1,2|LHR|DAC|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||322.000000|771.120000;1|TLXN2XPC|FB05|TK|1|||3,4|DAC|LHR|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||0.000000|0.000000ÞÞGBP1093.12",
        "lastTicketingDate": "2022-01-11T23:59:59",
        "legFareClass": "Economy",
        "supportedfunctions": "None",
        "requirementValues": 0,
        "numStops": 0,
        "departureDate": "",
        "origin": "",
        "arrivalDate": "",
        "destination": "",
        "airsegments": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "carrierCode": "TK",
        "outboundAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "legtraveltime": "PT16H25M",
        "totalJourneyTime": 0,
        "recordSet": "GDS@PUBLISHED@E@1|UN3FEST|FB00|TK|1||ADT=ADT,CHD=CHD|1,2|LHR|DAC|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||322.000000|771.120000;1|TLXN2XPC|FB05|TK|1|||3,4|DAC|LHR|20220208|20220221|1|||0|||0.000000|0.000000ÞÞGBP1093.12",
        "lastTicketingDate": "2022-01-11T23:59:59",
        "legFareClass": "Economy",
        "supportedfunctions": "None",
        "requirementValues": 0,
        "numStops": 0,
        "departureDate": "",
        "origin": "",
        "arrivalDate": "",
        "destination": "",
        "airsegments": null
    }
]`

    j2 := `[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-09T00:30:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-09",
        "ArrivalTime": "00:30:00",
        "bookingclass": "U",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "LHR",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-08T17:40:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-08",
        "DepartureTime": "17:40:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "UN3FEST/FB00",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "1972",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "DAC",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-09T13:55:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-09",
        "ArrivalTime": "13:55:00",
        "bookingclass": "U",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "IST",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-09T03:35:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-09",
        "DepartureTime": "03:35:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "UN3FEST/FB00",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "712",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-22T05:40:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-22",
        "ArrivalTime": "05:40:00",
        "bookingclass": "T",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "DAC",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-21T23:30:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-21",
        "DepartureTime": "23:30:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "TLXN2XPC/FB05",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "723",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "LHR",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-22T09:55:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-22",
        "ArrivalTime": "09:55:00",
        "bookingclass": "T",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "IST",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-22T08:50:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-22",
        "DepartureTime": "08:50:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "TLXN2XPC/FB05",
        "faretype": "Negotiated",
        "FlightNumber": "1979",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Cat35",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "availstring": "TK-1972-LHR-IST-202202081740-MG:O@C:TK@|TK-712-IST-DAC-202202090335-MG:I@C:TK@||LEG=1",
        "flightType": "",
        "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST",
        "arrivaldatetime": "2022-02-09T00:30:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "2022-02-09",
        "ArrivalTime": "00:30:00",
        "bookingclass": "U",
        "cabinclass": "Y",
        "CabinClass": "Economy",
        "OperatingAirlineCode": "TK",
        "image": "https://travnet-tse-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/airline-logo/TK.png",
        "DepartureAirportCode": "LHR",
        "departuredatetime": "2022-02-08T17:40:00",
        "DepartureDate": "2022-02-08",
        "DepartureTime": "17:40:00",
        "equipmentcode": "333",
        "equipmentname": "",
        "farebase": "UN3FEST",
        "faretype": "Published",
        "FlightNumber": "1972",
        "freebaggageallowance": "",
        "freeseats": 9,
        "mealcode": "",
        "subfaretype": "Standard",
        "journeyDuration": 0
    }
]`

    type Airsegments struct {
        ID                 int    `json:"id"`
        Availstring        string `json:"availstring"`
        ArrivalAirportCode string
    }

    type Flights struct {
        Availstring string        `json:"availstring"`
        Airsegments []Airsegments `json:"airsegments"`
    }

    var flights []Flights
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j1), &flights)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var airsegments []Airsegments
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(j2), &airsegments)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for fi, flt := range flights {
        for _, arg := range airsegments {
            if arg.Availstring == flt.Availstring {
                flights[fi].Airsegments = append(flights[fi].Airsegments, arg)
            }
        }
    }

    flightssJson, err := json.MarshalIndent(flights, "  ", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(flightssJson))
}
```

The output it produces:

```json
[
    {
      "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
      "airsegments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
          "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "availstring": "PUB @1|LHR|TK+1972+202202081740+|TK+712+202202090335+|DAC@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
          "ArrivalAirportCode": "DAC"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
      "airsegments": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
          "ArrivalAirportCode": "IST"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "availstring": "PUB @1|DAC|TK+723+202202212330+|TK+1979+202202220850+|LHR@@AVL:X|X|X|X",
          "ArrivalAirportCode": "LHR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @dev please consider marking the answer as "accepted" so others may find it in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can always put those 2 json-texts inside another:

```
{
  "firstModel": XXX
  "secondModel": YYY
}
```

if XXX is the content of your first  and YYY is the second,
then you can address both of them separately.